# Количество обращений к static полю класса

Tags: java, классы

Требуется посчитать количество обращений (*set* и *get*) к `private static` полю класса `MyClass`.

Правильный ли подход к решению этого вопроса применен ниже?

```
class MyClass {
    private static String str = "example string";
    private static Integer countGetSet = 0;

    public static String getString() {

        countGetSet++;
        return str;
    }

    public static void setString(String inStr) {
        str = inStr;
        countGetSet++;
    }

    public static Integer getСountGetSet() {

        return countGetSet;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все зависит сильно от ситуации.

Если у вас один объект данного класса, то можно завернуть его в прокси и при каждом вызове методов увеличивать счетчик. Тем самым вы сохраняете измеряемый класс в нетронутом виде. Это можно сделать либо через `стандартный прокси`, либо через `AspectJ`, либо через `mockito`.

Так же, можете, использовать паттерны проектирования и создать `декоратор` для данного класса. При вызове метода, вы увеличиваете счетчик и затем делегируете выполнение методу измеряемого класса.

Ваш же вариант, наиболее простой, но тут видны проблемы с многопоточностью. Этот код не  `thread-safe`. Вместо `Integer` воспользуйтесь `AtomicInteger` чтобы сделать его таковым.

Comment: если использовать AtomicInteger будет thread-safe?

Comment: @AdamSkywalker будет

Comment: @BogdanK не угадал

Comment: @AdamSkywalker _Этот код не  thread-safe. Вместо Integer воспользуйтесь AtomicInteger чтобы сделать его таковым._

Comment: @BogdanK намёки на синхронизацию доступа к переменной не зашли

Comment: Integer не гаратирует атомарности, а AmomicInteger гарантирует, следовательно при одновременном увеличении счетчика из разных потоков с AtomicInteger все будет хорошо работать, в отличии от Integer